# How to use a single regex to extract a substring from this string?

Tags: regex

I have these strings:

**Case 1: System returned to ROM by unknown reload cause - reason ptr 0xBFC2B644, PC 0x60452AC0, address 0x0 at 16:03:27 MSD Thu Jun 8 2006**

output should be: unknown reload cause - reason ptr 0xBFC2B644, PC 0x60452AC0, address 0x0 (string between "by" and "at")

**Case 2: System returned to ROM by watchdog timer expired**

output should be: watchdog timer expired (String after "by" till the end since "at" is not present)

**How can i use a regex to extract the substring between "by" and "at"(if "at" is not present then string from by till the end)**

This regex i came up with matches the substring only if the string has the at part.

*(?<=by)(.*)?(at)+(?!at\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s.*?\d\s+\d\d\d\d)*

**String i used to check:** a SegV exception, PC 0x325D558 at 20:34:38 UTC Fri Jun

**output for the above regex:** error - a SegV exception, PC 0x325D558

Comment: Eclipse is a development environment used to program in many different languages, what language are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
.* by (.*)(( at )|$)
```

replace with $1

see [this](https://regex101.com/r/dXPJLc/1)

Comment: I tried this but its returning everything after "at" if its present. Thanks mate.

Comment: I made this modification to your regex patttern to make it work: by (.*?)((at\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s.*?\d\s+\d\d\d\d)$|$). Thanks a ton!

Comment: Small mistake :)
should be 
`.* by (.*)(( at .*)|$)`
[see this](https://regex101.com/r/dXPJLc/2)

Answer (score 0):

hopefully i understand you right.
The following regex should solve you problem.

```
(.*?by[ ]*)(.*?)(([ ]at[ ])|$)(.*?)
// Group $1 - (.*?by[ ]*)    Should contain all information in front of searched text
// Group $2 - (.*?)          Should contain your searched string
// Group $3 - (([ ]at[ ])|$) Should contain the word 'at' or nothing
// Group $4 - (.*?)          Should contain the rest of the string, if text contains 'at'
```

I've tested the regex in Notepad++ for the following strings:

1.) Case 1: System returned to ROM by unknown reload cause - reason ptr 0xBFC2B644, PC 0x60452AC0, address 0x0 at 16:03:27 MSD Thu Jun 8 2006

2.) System returned to ROM by watchdog timer expired

And got the following results when replaced the regex with the group $2

1.) unknown reload cause - reason ptr 0xBFC2B644, PC 0x60452AC0, address 0x0
2.) watchdog timer expired

*Note: Ensure that the language you are working with does not handle "." in a regex as newline.

Comment: We use RLP engine and i tried using the RegEx you made and the output i get is "by". Regex Parser Language (RPL) is a specialized language, engine and SDK for parsing text data and transforming it into XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
by (.*?)((at\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s.*?\d\s+\d\d\d\d)$|$)
\\Group1 - Matches everything
\\Group2 - Matches the string after "at" ($ because nothing follows it)
 **\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s.*?\d\s+\d\d\d\d** matches the following kind of **string 16:03:27 MSD Thu Jun 8 2006**
```

**These are the outputs i got:**
**1.** System returned to ROM by unknown reload cause - reason ptr 0xBFC2B644, PC 0x60452AC0, address 0x0 at 16:03:27 MSD Thu Jun 8 2006

Output: unknown reload cause - reason ptr 0xBFC2B644, PC 0x60452AC0, address 0x0

**2.** System returned to ROM by watchdog timer expired

Output: watchdog timer expired